# Most memorable titles

Tags: soft-question, ho.history-overview, big-list, mathematical-writing, math-communication

Given the vast number of new papers / preprints that hit the internet everyday, one factor that may help papers stand out for a broader, though possibly more casual, audience is their title. This view was my motivation for asking this question almost 7 years ago (*wow!*), and it remains equally true today (those who subscribe to arXiv feeds, MO feeds, etc., may agree).

---

I was wondering if the MO-users would be willing to share their wisdom with me on what makes the title of a paper memorable for them; or perhaps just cite an example of title they find memorable?

This advice would be very helpful in helping me (and perhaps others) in designing better, more informative titles (not only for papers, but also for example, for MO questions).

One title that I find memorable is:

- **Nineteen dubious ways to compute the exponential of a matrix,** by Moler and van Loan.

---

The response to this question has been quite huge. So, what have I learned from it? A few things at least. Here is my summary of the obvious: Amongst the various "memorable" titles reported, some of the following are true:

1. A title can be *memorable*, *attractive*, or even both (to oversimplify a bit);
2. A title becomes truly *memorable* if the accompanying paper had memorable substance
3. A title can be attractive even without having memorable material.
4. To reach the broadest audience, attractive titles are good, though mathematicians might sometimes feel irritated by needlessly cute titles
5. Titles that are bold, are usually short, have an element of surprise, but do not depart too much from the truth seems to be more attractive in general.
   5.101 Mathematical succinctness might appeal to some people---but is perhaps not that memorable for me---so perhaps such titles are attractive, but maybe not memorable.
6. If you are a bigshot, you can get away with pretty much any title!

Comment: For news article and fiction, certainly; in some rare cases for expository material. But I can't say it's ever happened to me for math research articles (I'll post an almost-exception in the answers). And just as well, really, most papers have really dull titles! (The worst is when the titles are dull and vague.)

Comment: Of note is that the Moler-Van Loan paper also has a 20th anniversary update (also published in SIAM Reviews IIRC).

Comment: @Thierry: When I go article surfing on arXiv to discover new, potentially relevant articles, I often go by title alone. For fields that I am more familiar with, there the title is less determining.

Comment: I'd have put in "A Contribution to the Mathematical Theory of Big Game Hunting" as an answer, but that's carrying a joke too far I think.

Comment: If I find a paper by following a citation or recommendation or similar, then of course the title makes no difference.  But often I also find papers by browsing—on the arXiv, or on an author's list of publications, or similar—and then, a title that's eye-catching, descriptive, and mathematically interesting certainly does make a difference.  The same qualities are even more useful in an abstract.

Comment: Entertaining as this list may be, I seriously doubt that it will be a useful prescriptive guide as to how to title one's papers. Editors' and readers' tastes also change over the years

Comment: Since this question seems to have turned into a big list of "memorable/amusing paper titles," ignoring the primary question "what makes the title of a paper memorable?", perhaps it might be helpful to re-ask that question but without the loophole "...or perhaps just cite an example of title they find memorable".

Comment: I have an example of a title which could be an example in the negative direction. This was the first paper that I wrote in 1972 and the title was "on A_n(x,y;p,q) and F_n(x,y;p,q)". (A_n(x,y;p,q) was a notation from Riordan's "combinatorial identities" and F_n(x,y;p,q) was my own notation. Riordan was the referee and his first remark (in a long list) was that the title should be changed.  

Comment: Mike: memorable *to whom*?

Comment: @Yemon: to other mathematicians, I would presume.  Obviously there are differences, but surely there are generalities as well.

Comment: @Mike: I guess I am in the exceptional set, then. There is also the conflation of "memorable" with "arresting" or "interesting", and as you yourself have implied I think these are all different. I am much more likely to remember the core result of a paper, at least one of the authors, and the journal, than to remember the exact title. E.g. Haagerup's Inventiones paper proving that nuclear C*-algebras are amenable, or Gowers' GAFA paper giving a revolutionary new proof for Szemeredi length 4.

Comment: I have now caught a duplicate answer for the second time in as many days on this thread. To me this casts doubt on the usefulness of this thread, but I acknowledge that I have a long-standing bias against these types of questions, which from previous discussions on meta seems not to be shared by most people

Comment: Dear Yemon, I also have mixed feelings towards this and similar questions. Usually I would like to judge such big list questions more by the academic value and less by the entertaining value. But I still find it a lot of fun. And the answers are both entertaining and educational.

Comment: Just to make myself clear; Whether one likes or dislikes the problem I think it will not be appropriate to close it, it should stay open on its own merits, and certainly because of the attention it received.  

Comment: Many of the replies that are voted up below simply mention particular memorable titles.  One of my replies mentioned this one:

[Ancestors, Cardinals, and Representatives](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2323341) by T. D. Parsons.

This offended an anonymous person who will not step forward and explicitly explain why.  Can anyone shed any light on this?

And what exactly is the utility of encouraging anonymity in such matters, as this site does?

Comment: Is Suvrit going to reappear and tell us how useful this list of the droll and the Wildean has been in helping to write titles of papers?

Comment: It's not about drollness as an end-in-itself, or at least it shouldn't be.  Rather it's about drollness used to serve a purpose: to call people's attention to things worthy of attention and to help them remember things worth remembering.

Comment: @Yemon -- I am busy digesting these titles, and will try to summarize what I have learned from these titles. While the list might not directly help everybody, certainly many of the "memorable" titles are inspiring. Of course, just by staring at a list of great mathematicians, one cannot oneself become great, here too, by merely looking at the list, one cannot immediately start churning out good titles.

Comment: I liked this question, but somehow also feel it was open long enough. 
Thus I am contributing to already existing votes to close.

Comment: See also http://www.ncatlab.org/nlab/show/punny+title for more funny titles often including a pun or repetition, including the suggestion of Strøm's article which is also listed by Petersen, below.

Comment: http://www.guardian.co.uk/books/2010/feb/05/diagram-prize-oddest-title 

Comment: Arg, and I was so close to a Great Answer badge! :-)

Comment: I don't see anyone beating The Origin of Faeces. Although, for the actual Diagram Prize for that year, the winner was Crocheting Adventures with Hyperbolic Planes, for which part of the original idea was due to Bill Thurston.

Comment: One of the most memorable MO post titles is, in my opinion, here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/19152/why-is-a-topology-made-up-of-open-sets

Comment: For some reason no further answers can be posted, so let me share with you **Continuing horrors of topology without choice** by C. Good and I.J. Tree, and related to that **Horrors of topology without AC: A nonnormal orderable space** by E.K. van Douwen, **Disasters in topology without the axiom of choice** by K. Keremedis, **Disasters in metric topology without choice** by E. Tachtsis.

Comment: I quite like "A cottage industry of lax extensions" by Dirk Hofmann and Gavin J. Seal.

Comment: I am rather proud of the title of my paper "The Lie Lie algebra" https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.01192. There is a construction of an $\mathcal O$-Lie algebra for any cyclic operad $\mathcal O$, and the paper considers the case when $\mathcal O$ is the Lie operad.

Comment: New book from the American Math Society: Alice and Bob meet Banach. http://bookstore.ams.org/surv-223

Comment: A Radical Approach to Algebra by Mary W Gray https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/A_radical_approach_to_algebra.html?id=BIQZAQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y

Comment: I posted in the [colorful-language](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22299/what-are-some-examples-of-colorful-language-in-serious-mathematics-papers) thread, but it occurs to me it really goes here:  @TheoJohnson-Freyd's recent [post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/334536) reminded me of the paper [Griess and Ryba - Finite simple groups which projectively embed in an exceptional Lie group are classified!](http://www.ams.org/bull/1999-36-01/S0273-0979-99-00771-5).

Comment: I just stumbled upon "Counting your chickens with Markov chains" by David and Lori McCune

Comment: Once I went to a lecture entitled 'Happiness is not in pants'. It turned out to be about using triangles instead of pants to study surfaces.

Comment: Comments seem to be fun, diverse, and a good reflection of human nature, a plurality of human perspectives. What I applaud is that plurality without, in most cases, the need to destroy our mathematical culture.

Comment: About $6.$  Like The Who, "Tommy, A Rock Opera".  Since they got away with that, they did:  "White City:  A Novel".

Comment: It's not a title, but the abstract of Faltings' "Finiteness of coherent cohomology for proper fppf stacks" starts with "We prove the result in the title ...".

Answer (score 227):

I can't believe no one's mentioned this:

- Pavol Ševera, *Some title containing the words "homotopy" and "symplectic", e.g. this one*, [arXiv:math/0105080](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0105080)

Comment: I tend to remember this as and call it "Some title..."

Comment: inching towards the proverbial 100 $\uparrow$

Comment: Yes, it's my greatest claim to fame on MO.

Comment: Memorable yes, but I would not consider this a 'good title.' Titles should effectively communicate the content of the work, in addition to whatever good aesthetics, wittiness, etc. (nor though they be memes that encourage readers to not take the work seriously).

Comment: Very nice self reference you did there : I had to click on the arxiv link to see the very title you mentionned!

Answer (score 168):

The flattering lie  [You Could Have Invented Spectral Sequences](http://www.ams.org/notices/200601/fea-chow.pdf)  by Timothy Y. Chow.

Comment: subtitled "Also, that shirt looks good on you."

Comment: +1 because more people should learn of the existence of this paper.

Comment: Nice one.  I have sometimes wondered if I should have chosen a better title than _Prime Simplicity_ for my joint paper with Catherine Woodgold, setting the record straight about what Euclid did and did not do in a certain well-known but not-well-known proof.

Comment: There should be a series of "You Could Have Invented" papers.

Answer (score 167):

["Hodge's general conjecture is false for trivial reasons."](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~leila/grothendieckcircle/HodgeConj.pdf)

Comment: I love that title so much.

Comment: That is indeed a great title!

Comment: I dissent. This title is arrogant and vulgar ("trivial" is a ugly word), unworthy of Grothendieck who invented a lot of beautiful, decently modest, and often informative title, such as "Sur quelques points d'algèbre homologique" or "Récoltes et semailles", or "à la poursuite des champs". 

Comment: It is a modest title (though it might be taken to be offensive) - he doesn't say: "The Hodge Conjecture is false for very deep reasons and only I could have disproved it."

Comment: I don't think it's offensive at all -- all one has to do is read a few words of the paper to see that Grothendieck is merely performing a small but useful service. The title is catchy enough that one is easily invited to discover just that. 

Comment: If there is a paper explaining what Grothendieck actually says here, it may be worth mentioning the number of pages thereof :-)

Comment: Grothendieck's paper is 5 pages, and seems to explain itself pretty clearly.

Comment: I disagree.  The title is objective: he is simply saying that he has realised that the conjecture is false when one thinks carefully about it and that this escaped the attention of Hodge in formulating it.  I don't see the arrogance in that title, although I have seen it other works of Grothendieck that I have read.

Comment: Great. This title despite its seriousness left me with a big smile

Answer (score 161):

One that comes immediately to mind is [Can one hear the shape of a drum?](https://www.jstor.org/pss/2313748)

Comment: I've heard of this paper, but not read it. What is the answer ;-) ?

Comment: In brief, no; there are "drums" with different shapes but the same "sound". 

Comment: @Suvrit: Yes, but only if one knows a priori that the drum is convex.

Comment: Kac' question is still open for bounded smooth domains.

Comment: @SimonLyons: Sorry to revive this comment after almost eight years, but do you have a reference for the answer being "yes" in the convex case? I remember hearing in several discussions that the problem is still open even for convex two-dimensional domains with analytic boundary.

Comment: It was a long time ago and not my field - I think someone mentioned a result along those lines in a lecture I saw. This might be the right reference: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9901005

Answer (score 145):

[A minus sign that used to annoy me but now I know why it is there](https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.0555) by Peter Tingley.

Answer (score 136):

Mark Van Raamsdonk's Princeton PhD thesis in string theory was called "Making the most out of zero branes and a weak background". Priceless.

http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2000PhDT........40V

Answer (score 105):

My favourite :  ["My Graph"](http://plms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s3-46/1/117.abstract), by H.S.M. Coxeter.

Comment: My graph brings all the boys to the yard?

Comment: Maybe that's the graph that Nickelback wanted to show us all along?

Answer (score 92):

Given the atmosphere of terror and fear in recent years, I did a double take when I first glanced at Bruce Berndt's paper "[Ramanujan's association with radicals in India](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2974470.pdf)".

Comment: That reminds me of a course description from the Harvard course catalogue, circa 1970: something like, "The theory of blowing up, with special attention to local problems." Fortunately, this was offered by the Department of Mathematics, not Social Relations. 

Comment: I know this paper, but I'm not entirely sure Berndt was being deliberately provoking... :)

Comment: In my experience with him I'd say he wasn't, but there's a streak in him I wouldn't put it past.

Comment: @GerryMyerson about blowing up, see also the story about the algebraic geometry people at airport security, at http://mathoverflow.net/a/53738/5340 (and previously at http://mathoverflow.net/a/23074/5340 )

Answer (score 84):

John Stallings' ["How not to prove the Poincare Conjecture"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.32.3404) is lovely.

Answer (score 84):

And in the graph theory corner we have the famous Harary/Read paper "Is the null-graph a pointless concept?"

Comment: This epic paper appears in *Lecture Notes in Math.*, vol. 406, Springer, 1974, 37-44. The abstract is the following:

The graph with no points and no lines is discussed critically. Arguments for and against its official admittance as a graph are presented. This is accompanied by an extensive survey of the literature. Paradoxical properties of the null-graph are noted. No conclusion is reached.


Comment: I don't know now whether i like the abstract more or the title; absolutely fantastic.

Comment: I like the title more.  There are many cases where the degenerate case is hard:  0!, a^0 vs 0^a, 1 is a prime, which we resolve by how many theorems need special cases.

Comment: @RossMillikan All answers are obvious for natural reasons: $0! = 1$, $a^0 = 1$, $0^a = 0$ for $a \geq 1$, 1 is not prime.

Answer (score 75):

[The book  $A=B$](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html).

Comment: Could you give a reference?

Comment: @Martin: I did: the text is a link (but MO+MathJax do not seem to underline or otherwise emphasize link when the linking text is just math) Googling for "A=B" gets you there, too.

Comment: Just add some other text to the ink, then - e.g. "The book A=B".

Comment: +1. This also brings to mind "Generatingfunctionology", which is itself pretty memorable.

Answer (score 70):

"[On $O_n$](https://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=602475)" by D.E. Evans.  ($\mathcal{O_n}$ is notation Cuntz gave for the algebras he introduced in "[Simple $C^*$-algebras generated by isometries](https://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=467330)".)

Comment: That resembles Connes/Consani's "Fun with F_1" - 1 in french is "un".

Comment: There is also the sequel, "On $O_{n+1}$" by Araki, Carey, and Evans: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=757434

Comment: Have you ever tried to google that paper (without knowing who wrote it, of course)? Hopeless! :-)

Comment: @Ulrich: The first result that Google Scholar returns when I type On O_n into it is precisely this paper.  I wouldn't exactly say that googling this paper is “hopeless”.

Comment: @Dmitri: I just tried that in Google Scholar and it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 58):

[A Midsummer Knot's Dream](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.4494), by Allison Henrich, Noël MacNaughton, Sneha Narayan, Oliver Pechenik, Robert Silversmith, Jennifer Townsend

It is quite funny to read

Answer (score 56):

The AKS paper [PRIMES is in P](http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/manindra/algebra/primality_v6.pdf) is a pretty memorable title for me.

Comment: Certainly it's a memorable title, but I keep having to fight the urge to reply "No, they isn't!"  I would have preferred a title like "Deterministic, polynomial-time primality testing," but that would not have been memorable, so perhaps they made the right choice.

Comment: I guess I should have put in my motivation: while I'm not normally interested in number theory, the title "jumped" at me, so to speak.

Comment: @Henry, to be fair, the title was actually "PRIMES is in P", where 'PRIMES' refers not to the set of primes, but the (hypothetical) (deterministic) algorithm to test for primality.

Comment: Actually, it does refer to the set of primes (see the first page of the article).  I agree that the title is syntactically correct; I'm just bothered by how it sounds when you read it out loud.

Answer (score 55):

[Everybody knows what a Hopf algebra is](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&r=1&review_format=html&s4=bergman&s5=everybody%20knows&s6=&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq)

Answer (score 55):

[Zaphod Beeblebrox's Brain and the Fifty-ninth Row of Pascal's Triangle](http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/beeb.pdf)

Answer (score 52):

[Finding composite order ordinary elliptic curves using the Cocks-Pinch method](http://eprint.iacr.org/2009/533.pdf), by D. Boneh, K. Rubin and A. Silverberg.  (To appear in the Journal of Number Theory.)

Comment: +1 because I'm so shallow. :D

Comment: We have ways of making number theorists talk... 

Comment: Journal of Number Theory, Vol. 131 (5), 2011, pp. 832-841.

Comment: This is obviously in direct contrast to the [Cox-Zucker machine](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cox%E2%80%93Zucker_machine).

Answer (score 48):

I find it dubious that anyone here will get better at choosing titles for their papers by reading these examples.

Nevertheless, I like the title "*The homotopy category is a homotopy category*" by Arne Strøm. I also like the very apt title "$\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{22}$ *is of general type*" by Gavril Farkas. The paper starts like this:

The aim of this paper is to prove the following result:

**Theorem:** The moduli space of curves of genus 22 is of general type.

Comment: Yes: a title can be effectively eye-catching not just by being humorous or off the wall, but also simply by being very mathematically expressive and succinct.

Answer (score 48):

The paper *[Division by three](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0605779)* by Peter G. Doyle and John Horton Conway

Comment: Reading this paper is a pure moment of happiness! (Except for figure 2, which makes look complicated a proof which is perfectly clear when expressed in words).

Comment: And, one-upping this title: [Patrick Lutz, *Conway Can Divide by Three, But I Can’t*](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~pglutz/division_by_three.pdf).

Answer (score 47):

**The missing axiom of matroid theory is lost forever**

A emotional variation on absolute negative results.
Refs : Vámos, Peter (1978), "The missing axiom of matroid theory is lost forever", Journal of the London Mathematical Society, II. Ser. 18:
AT : http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s2-18/3/403.extract

Answer (score 46):

A Group of Order 8,315,553,613,086,720,000 by J H Conway, Bull. London Math. Soc. (1969) 1 (1): 79-88, https://doi.org/10.1112/blms/1.1.79

Maybe it's cheating to call this memorable - I remembered there was a Conway paper with a title of this type, but I certainly don't claim to have remembered the exact title!

Comment: I'm told that shortly after the Hall-Wales paper "The Simple Group of Order 604,800" (J. Algebra 9 (1968), 417-450) was published, the editors received an anonymous submission entitled "The Simple Group of Order 604,801".  Sure enough, 604801 is prime.

Comment: There's also a Youtube video called Finite Simple Group (of Order Two), https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTby_e4-Rhg

Answer (score 44):

[An application of Poincaré's recurrence theorem to academic administration](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2320708) by Kenneth Meyer is a title that is hard to resist looking into.

Comment: This is absolutely hilarious... and only one page long. It's a MUST read.

Comment: Here's a link that does not require a JSTOR account: https://math.uc.edu/~meyer/Administration.pdf

Comment: That link didn't work for me, but https://www.math.uh.edu/~tomforde/ArticlesUL/Academia.pdf did.

Comment: As of 2021 neither of the above links works, but http://www1.mate.polimi.it/~bramanti/caffe/materidere/poincare.htm does.

Comment: Well, guess what. https://marktomforde.com/academic/miscellaneous/images/Academia.pdf

Answer (score 40):

I always remember the paper entitled "On groups of order one."  It turned out the title referred to groups defined by generators and relations, so the problem was to determine when a set of elements (together with its conjugates) generated a free group.  I cannot imagine any mathematician who would not look at this paper to see what it was about.

Answer (score 37):

The book *[Free rings and their relations](https://books.google.com/books?id=R3KmAAAAIAAJ&q=inauthor%3A%2522Paul+Moritz+Cohn%2522&dq=inauthor%3A%2522Paul+Moritz+Cohn%2522&hl=en&ei=jNfNTOfdLsyjnQe7wL3ZCQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=book-thumbnail&resnum=3&ved=0CC4Q6wEwAjgK)* by P.M. Cohn.

Comment: +1: I've encountered that book many times during trips to the stacks over the past dozen years or so.  Every time I stop and scratch my head.  One day I suppose I'll actually read it...

Answer (score 37):

Very late addition (August '13) J. J. Sylvester, **Thoughts on inverse orthogonal matrices, simultaneous sign-successions and tesselated pavements in two or more colors, with applications to Newton rule, Ornamental tile-work, and the theory of numbers**. Phil Mag 34 (**1867**), 461-475.

This title is unbeatable!

Late addition (March, '13): Long and Wigderson's "  **How discreet is the discrete log?**."

Gale and Shapley's "**College Admissions and the Stability of Marriage**, " was a great title to a great paper. ([link JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2312726))

"**Moments in mathematics**" Papers from the American Mathematical Society annual meeting held in San Antonio, Tex., January 20–22, 1987. Edited by Henry J. Landau. ([Link: Google book](https://www.google.com/books?hl=iw&lr=&id=IEo2Iu_uogUC&oi=fnd&pg=PR11&dq=moments+in+mathematics&ots=GnVLCNdqjp&sig=3RsGo_81JwPL1xFRUvmkHzEGVWA#v=onepage&q&f=false))

This is about "moments" in the technical sense but the double meaning of the title is very cute. (There is also a book entitled "great moments in mathematics" with the ordinary meaning of moments.)

About 1-2 decades ago Sylvain Cappell and Shmuel Weinberger planned writing a book called "**A piece of the action**" about group actions. This is a memorable title but I think the book was not completed.

One obvious: Aigner and Ziegler's **Proofs from the book**. ([Link: WikipediA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_from_THE_BOOK))

Joel Spencer's title "**Six standard deviations suffice**." is also memorable. ([Link: JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2000258))

Jack Edmonds',(1965) "**Paths, Trees and Flowers**". ([Link: ps file](http://libeccio.dia.unisa.it/ASDII/2004/edmonds.ps).)

For some reasons I found the title "**Defect Sauer results**" of a paper by Bollobas and Radcliffe memorable. ([Link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316595900608))

Branko Grunbaum has a paper entiled "**The importance of being straight**" (I could not find a link), and Irit Dinur and Shmuel Safra have a paper entitled "**On the importance of being biased**". ([A link to a later version with a different title.](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/%7Edinuri/mypapers/vc.pdf))
(There is [a paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1290259) by A. Dillof published in Michigan Law Review with very similar name.)

Jorg Wills had a memorable title "**decomposable skeleta**" for a paper he sent for the 100th birthday of a well known mathematician. But I think at the end he changed the title.

Saharon Shelah has several memorable titles like this one: **"On what I do not understand (and have something to say). I**" .Although, I forgot the most memorable one.

Comment: If you forgot it (last sentence), it couldn't have been the most memorable! :-)  Maybe "The last forcing standing"?

Comment: It is a real shame if the one involving skeleta got its title changed!

Comment: You may be thinking of "You can enter Cantor's paradise". It is also worth mentioning that Shelah numbers his publications, and reserves special numbers for significant papers. Paper 666 is the one you mentioned. 

Comment: Well, I thought about a paper where the title or part of it was "Why am I happy". But I couldn't find it.

Comment: I think giving the number 666 to that particular paper was not Saharon Shelah's idea but Andrzej Roslanowski's.  Andrzej was (and probably still is) in charge of maintaining the Shelah archive.

Comment: I think "Why I am so happy" was the title of an abstract by Shelah, but the paper probably got a more serious title (involving the "main gap").

Comment: The Shela very nice title "On what I do not understand (and have something to say)" 
It is useful for some (including myself) to know that it is a reference to Wittgenstein quote: 

"Whereof one cannot speak, thereof one must be silent"


Comment: Really nice find about Sylvester's title!

Comment: "There is also a book entitled 'great moments in mathematics' with the ordinary meaning of moments." Actually, there are two, by Howard Eves; one is called Great Moments in Mathematics Before 1650, the other, Great Moments in Mathematics After 1650. I'm still waiting for the third volume, Great Moments in Mathematics During 1650.

Answer (score 37):

Here is [a list of papers in Theoretical Computer Science with cute titles](http://www2.tcs.ifi.lmu.de/%7Ejjohanns/cute.html). Some that I like from the list (aside from "Mick gets some" which is good enough to deserve its own answer anyway).

- A Smaller Sleeping Bag for a Baby Snake
- The Art of Pointless Thinking: a Student's Guide to the Category of Locales
- Scott is not always sober

Also: [Mangoes and Blueberries](https://doi.org/10.1007/s004930050056).

And in a similar vein, a quote from "Quotients homophone des groupes libres - Homophonic quotients of free groups," that appears on the first linked page page: *"Ah, la recherche! Du temps perdu."*

Comment: +1 for mentioning that last dazzling paper

Comment: The last phrase of "Scott is not always sober": $\underline{\text{Acrostic}}$ apologies, in conclusion, to Dana Scott for the wholly unjustified slur on his good name in the title of this article.

Answer (score 37):

"I know I should have taken that left turn at Albuquerque" by Gady Kozma and Ariel Yadin (https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.4258)

Comment: You should have informed a certain user on this site about this, and let them post it.

Answer (score 33):

["Holey Sheets" - Pfaffians and Subdeterminants as D-brane Operators in Large N Gauge Theories.](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0211152)

Comment: Now I want to read this one! :D

Answer (score 31):

[Integrity of ghosts](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0612443), by Gert Almkvist.

[Gert Almkvist's generalization of a mistake by Bourbaki](https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/%7Ezeilberg/mamarim/mamarimhtml/gert.html), by Doron Zeilberger. (And [a few more](https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/%7Ezeilberg/papers1.html) by the same author.)

[The Point of Pointless Topology](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1983-08-01/S0273-0979-1983-15080-2/S0273-0979-1983-15080-2.pdf), by Peter Johnstone.

The absolute classic: [Go To Statement Considered Harmful](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd02xx/EWD215.PDF), by Edsger Dijkstra.

Comment: Memorable, but that last one is a computer science paper...

Comment: $\mathrm{ComputerScience}\subset\mathrm{Math}$.

Comment: Mariano, the Library of Congress agrees with you, QA76 $\subset$ QA. 

Comment: Dang, I was about to go post "The Point of Pointless Topology." Anyway, I'd give you +1 for for the Dijkstra paper alone

Comment: "Disturbing the Dyson Conjecture (in a GOOD Way)" by Andrew V. Sills and Doron Zeilberger (Exp. Math. 15 (2006), 187-191) is especially GOOD. (To whom it concerns, "Good" is for "Jack Good", a combinatorialist.)

Answer (score 31):

[There are not exactly five objects](https://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2274177)
by Andreas Blass

Comment: OK, now I'm wondering, does anyone know what Morley's solution for the p=5 case was?

Comment: I learned later that "my" proof had actually been published earlier by Kenneth Appel.  I can't find any record of what Morley's 1977 proof was, but later, in 1984, Morley sent me a short formula that does the job (for arbitrary primes):
$\forall x_0\dots x_{p-1}\,\exists t_0\dots t_{p-1}
\bigwedge_{\sigma\in
  p^p}\big((\bigwedge_{i=0}^{p-1}t_i=x_{\sigma(i)})\to x_{F_0(\sigma)}=x_{F_1(\sigma)}\big)$ where $F_0,F_1:p^p\to p$ are chosen so that for all $\sigma$, $F_0(\sigma)\neq F_1(\sigma)$ and if $\sigma$ is not one-to-one, then $\sigma(F_1(\sigma))=\sigma(F_0(\sigma))$.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416648/how-hard-is-it-to-say-not-exactly-p-with-a-horn-sentence

Answer (score 29):

Atiyah's [K-Theory and Reality](http://www.math.rochester.edu/u/faculty/doug/otherpapers/AtiyahKthyReal.pdf)

Answer (score 27):

H=W

It's a paper showing that two methods of defining Sobolev spaces, one which uses H's with subscripts and superscripts and one that uses W's, give rise to the same spaces.

Thanks to Willie Wong for the following:

**Citation information**

```
@ARTICLE{MeySer1964,
  author = {Meyers, Norman G. and Serrin, James},
  title = {{H = W}},
  journal = {Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci. USA},
  year = {1964},
  volume = {51},
  pages = {1055-1056},
  number = {6},
  file = {MeySer1964.pdf:MeySer1964.pdf:PDF},
  owner = {ww278},
  timestamp = {2010.05.03},
  url = {http://www.pnas.org/content/51/6/1055.short}
}
```

Comment: I added the citation info, since this is CW, I just pasted it in, hope you don't mind. 

Comment: (BTW, this was also the first thing that came to mind when I read the title of this question.)

Comment: Even shorter, at least in print, is $c_p$ by C.A. McCarthy (Israel. J. Math. 5, 249--271 (1967)), about the Schatten classes..

Answer (score 26):

I'm quite surprised that no one has mentioned [The Joy of Sets](https://books.google.com/books?id=hCv-vFu4jskC&lpg=PP1&ots=Je0jT8O-A7&dq=the%2520joy%2520of%2520sets&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false) by [Keith Devlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keith_Devlin).

Comment: Ah, that's what "The Joy of Cats" (a category theory book) referred to.

Comment: Actually both book are spin on a famous book by Alex Comfort. Either way, the first edition of "The Joy of Cats" dealt with its theme very nicely. There were many illustrations featuring cats.

Comment: In fact, the Alex Comfort book was based on Irma Rombauer’s classic cookbook “The Joy of Cooking”, from 1931.  As far as I know, this meme goes back no further…

Comment: Michael Spivak has published a [book in this vein about typesetting](https://www.amazon.com/Gourmet-Typesetting-AMSTeX-Package-Second/dp/0821829971).

Comment: I would be certain that the name was hinting at this [1972 book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Joy_of_Sex)

Answer (score 25):

[Homotopy Algebras are Homotopy Algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9907138)  by Martin Markl

Answer (score 24):

J.-M. FONTAINE
**Il n'y a pas de variété abélienne sur Z**
Invent. Math. (1985) 81, 515-538

Answer (score 23):

You'd think that with John H. Conway around, this should be like shooting fish in a barrel. One title that comes to mind is

- The Sensual (Quadratic) Form

and there are more goodies if you look at his [bibliography](http://www.math.princeton.edu/WebCV/ConwayBIB.pdf). For example,

- Character Calisthenics

or

- The $\sqrt{\text{Monster}}$ Construction

I also like the paper (both the title and the contents!) by Andreas Blass,

- [Seven Trees in One](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9405205)

Answer (score 20):

OK, fine... I'll confess I could not resist downloading from the arxiv the paper [Act globally, compute locally: group actions, fixed points, and localization](https://arxiv.org/abs/0710.5295). I don't know if it quite fits the question though, since I never **read** it (beyond the first couple of pages). It's just way too far outside of my main interests.

Answer (score 20):

Todd's ["The 'odd' number six."](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=MR&s1=11671)

Answer (score 20):

The book [Why Knot?](https://books.google.com/books?isbn=1931914222) by [Colin Adams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colin_Adams_(mathematician)).

Comment: Who is the author?

Comment: That was a good question! I am far from the business but saw the title on a desk of a colleague in Bonn about 4 years ago. The title was easily memorizable but not the name. I googled the latter...

Comment: There's also a set of notes for a knot theory course by Justin Roberts, called "Knot Knotes".

Answer (score 20):

I've always enjoyed the poetry of the title:

"Period three implies chaos"  -- T.-Y. Li & J. A. Yorke

Comment: Although, with the usual definition of chaos, period three doesn't imply it.

Answer (score 19):

- Andrew Stacey and Sarah Whitehouse, *The hunting of the Hopf ring*,
  Homology, Homotopy and Applications, Vol. 11 (2009), No. 2, pp.75-132. doi:[10.4310/HHA.2009.v11.n2.a6](https://doi.org/10.4310/HHA.2009.v11.n2.a6), arXiv:[0711.3722](https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.3722)

referencing [this poem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hunting_of_the_Snark). Much more memorable than the related works by the same authors:

- Andrew Stacey and Sarah Whitehouse, *Tall-Wraith monoids*, arXiv:[1102.3549](https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.3549)
- Andrew Stacey and Sarah Whitehouse, *Stable and unstable operations in mod $p$ cohomology theories*, Algebr. Geom. Topol. 8(2) (2008), 1059–1091, doi:[10.2140/agt.2008.8.1059](https://doi.org/10.2140/agt.2008.8.1059), arXiv:[math/0605471](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0605471)

Answer (score 19):

*Addictive Number Theory*, by Melvyn B. Nathanson.

Comment: This is the title of the introductory chapter to Additive Number Theory: Festschrift in Honor of the Sixtieth Birthday of Melvyn B Nathanson. 

Answer (score 19):

"Fun with $\mathbb{F}_{1}$"

https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.2401

Quite a decent pun, I think.

Comment: i thought this one had already been mentioned long ago? or am i mistaken?

Comment: It gets mentioned in a comment to this answer: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/44326/most-memorable-titles/44377#44377

Answer (score 19):

"The 40 billionth binary digit of pi is 1", D. Bailey and P. Borwein.

Answer (score 19):

At some point in time the [Erdős collaboration graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaboration_graph) did not contain an (induced) $K_5$, but it did contain a $K_5$ with one edge missing. Someone showed me a paper with a title something like "The Erdős graph contains a $K_5$," written by the two authors that formed the missing edge. The rest of the paper was blank, since the names of the authors were sufficient to prove the statement of the title. Not really a memorable title *per se*, but it becomes quite memorable when the authors are included.  I couldn't find any mention of this paper on the web, however.

Comment: Something like this was posted as a math joke to reddit, https://www.reddit.com/r/MathJokes/comments/gebnnl/5_mathematicians_coauthor_a_paper_titled_the/

Comment: Surely it would have also needed a bibliography?

Answer (score 18):

"Footnote To a Note of Davenport and Heilbronn" by J. W. S. Cassels.

https://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s1-36/1/177.extract

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get it.  It's a nice paper, certainly, but what's memorable about the title?

Comment: Perhaps it is because "footnote to a note" makes one imagine the entire paper as written in a tiny, tiny font?

Comment: Or that the entire paper is a footnote?

Comment: @adamo: Two students in our institute wrote their master thesis based on a book written with typewriter in which a footnote roughly in the middle never ended and became the main text.

Comment: Nabokov's novel, Pale Fire, is mostly footnotes.

Comment: I've noticed that such (fake?) modest titles such as "A remark on..." where quite common at that time. This might have be a mockery of this fashion, assuming this purported to be a joke.

Answer (score 18):

Lovasz's "Hit and Run Is Fast and Fun". In that he proved the hit run algorithm on sampling from log concave distributions on a convex set in the Euclidean space has a polynomial mixing time, hence fast.

Answer (score 18):

My memory is marked by the titles of two papers by Branko Grünbaum:

1. Branko Grünbaum. `[Are your polyhedra the same as my polyhedra?](http://www.math.washington.edu/%7Egrunbaum/Your%2520polyhedra-my%2520polyhedra.pdf1.1.)' *Discrete and comput. Geom.: the Goodman-Pollack Festschrift*, ed. B. Aronov et al, Springer (2003), pp. 461-488.
2. Branko Grünbaum. `[The Bilinski Dodecahedron and Assorted Parallelohedra, Zonohedra, Monohedra, Isozonohedra, and Otherhedra](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00283-010-9138-7)'. *The Mathematical Intelligencer* (2010). DOI: 10.1007/s00283-010-9138-7.

The first title is easy for me to recall whenever I need to refer to the paper. The second title sounds fancy (though the article itself is not) and, more importantly, is unpronounceable by me, therefore I have put some stretch of mental effort into memorising it.

As to the original question---What makes the title of a paper memorable?---, personally, when I look for things to read, my attention tends to be captured by titles that are short and sweet, for instance, Jean-Pierre Serre's *Trees*, Ken Brown's *Buildings*. These monographs/papers usually turn out to be the authoritative treaties of the topics, with material unforgettable for one working in the field.

Comment: Books were writ by Archimedes, but only Serre could call one Trees.

Answer (score 17):

[Approximately counting up to four](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/258533.258663), by Luby and Vigoda.

Answer (score 17):

Paul Halmos' *Applied Mathematics is Bad Mathematics* is certainly a memorable title, notwithstanding the wrong-headedness of what at least superficially appears to be its thesis.

Answer (score 16):

I don't think $\textbf{L'endoscopie tordue n'est pas si tordue}$ (Twisted endoscopy is not so twisted) de J.-L. Waldspurger has been mentioned yet.

Answer (score 16):

Ben Andrews' : "Gauss curvature flow: the fate of the rolling stones"

Answer (score 16):

One of my favorite titles from control theory is a 1978 paper by John Doyle entitled "Guaranteed Margins for LQG Regulators." It is memorable because of the abstract "There are none." The paper shows that optimal controls may be fragile; the 3-word abstract says it all.

Answer (score 15):

[On the Dreaded Right Bousfield Localization](http://www.math.ias.edu/~clarkbar/docs/remark2.pdf) by C. Barwick.

Answer (score 15):

[**Ideals and reality**](https://books.google.com/books?id=P82xkbGioL8C)

projective modules and number of generators of ideals

By Friedrich Ischebeck and Ravi A. Rao

Answer (score 15):

There are some rather obvious aspects to the question that perhaps should be mentioned.

"For a large number of readers, the choice whether they select to read a paper or not is often strongly influenced by the title."

Yes, but it is also strongly influenced by the abstract and introduction.

"I was wondering if the MO-users would be willing to share their wisdom with me on what makes the title of a paper memorable for them; or perhaps just cite an example of title they find memorable?"

Since most answers refereed to the second part, perhaps it is worth answering the first part of the question as well. Perhaps the main thing that makes the title (and paper) memorable is the content of the paper.

"This advice would be very helpful in helping me (and perhaps others) in designing better, more informative titles (not only for papers, but also for example, for MO questions)."

Overall, the reaction in the mathematics community to catchy titles, personal descriptions, jokes of various kind, and various other things that can be seen as PR-related or "salesmanship" are mixed. So while it is always good to have a clear title having an overly catchy title can also backfire.

Comment: I think given the papers that I have seen being cited here, a conservative moral might be: the more powerful the content (or the writer) of the paper, the bolder the title one may select. More important to me is to figure out a good balance between catchyness, precision, and informativeness. I would not want to sacrifice the latter two in favor of the first one, unless I had a breakthrough result.

Comment: I would put it more strongly: if you are in the position that the community won't mind your papers having catchy titles, then you probably aren't reading MO to get advice.

Answer (score 15):

[Street-Fighting Mathematics](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-098-street-fighting-mathematics-january-iap-2008/readings/) by Sanjoy Mahajan is about estimation, Fermi calculations, dimensional analysis and so on.

I haven't read it yet, but the title was certainly enough to get me to download it.

Comment: The link you provide doesn't work. can you, please, fix it?

Answer (score 15):

From the top of my head comes the papers

- [Domination When The Stars Are Out](https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.0012), D Hermelin, M Mnich, EJ van Leeuwen, G Woeginger
- Looking At The Stars, E Prieto & C Sloper
- [Leftovers from the Ham Sandwich Theorem](http://www.latrobe.edu.au/mathstats/staff/cairns/papers/36.pdf), G Byrnes, G Cairns and B Jessup

But also, Cox & Zucker, who in [Intersection numbers of sections of elliptic surfaces](http://www.ii.uib.no/%7Esloper/Papers/stars_web.pdf) creates the algorithm later named the **Cox-Zucker machine**

Comment: Great one :) ${}$

Answer (score 15):

[How often should you beat your kids?](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0025570X.1990.11977493), by Don Zagier. The conclusion is that you should beat your kids every day except Sunday!

The word "beat" in this context means to defeat your child in a certain card guessing game, which the paper shows that you will win with asymptotic probability $\frac12+\frac1{2\sqrt{2}}\approx\frac{6}7$, hence six days out of seven.

Despite the intentionally shocking title, the paper is quite a good read!

Answer (score 14):

Noone beats [Mick gets some (the odds are on his side)](http://www.computer.org/plugins/dl/pdf/proceedings/focs/1992/2900/00/0267789.pdf?template=1&loginState=1&userData=anonymous-IP%25253A%25253AAddress%25253A%252B83.92.99.205%25252C%252B%25255B83.92.99.205%25252C%252B172.16.161.5%25252C%252B127.0.0.1%25255D) by V. Chvatal and B. Reed. It is an article about the satisfiability problem, and the title is of course referring to [this song](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QpZ3dVpE_pY). I havn't read the article, and the only reason I know the it is its title.

Answer (score 14):

There was the fuss about [The Yellow Cake](http://www.unomaha.edu/logic/pictures/yellow/yellow.html), a joint paper of Saharon Shelah and Andrzej Roslanowski. ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20100312034655/https://www.unomaha.edu/logic/pictures/yellow/yellow.html))

They also co-authored several other funnily titled papers, amongst them are such names as:

- "[How much sweetness is there in the universe?](https://arxiv.org/abs/math.LO/0406612)"
- "[Measured Creatures](https://arxiv.org/abs/math.LO/0010070)"
- "[Lords of the iteration](https://arxiv.org/abs/math.LO/0611131)"
- "[Sweet & Sour and other flavours of ccc forcing notions](https://arxiv.org/abs/math.LO/9909115)"

Comment: How can we talk about sweetness without mentioning Saccharinity?  http://shelah.logic.at/files/859.pdf
:)

Comment: Hello hello, this is a test!

Answer (score 13):

Fractured Fractals And Broken Dreams. Self-similar Geometry through Metric and Measure. Guy David, Stephen Semmes.

http://www.oup.com.au/titles/academic/maths/9780198501664

This is the most unusual title of a book which I have ever come across. I discovered this  while randomly browsing through books in the library and got hooked. I was an undergraduate then and it had a strange attraction to me, even though I could not figure out anything that was written in it then.

I was not the only one!

Our university used to put out a list of courses (in the good old days) which were going to be offered and students would choose from it. Some of us managed to add the name of this book against the fractal geometry course as a course material. A record number of students enlisted.

Within a week a record number of them wanted to opt out. So there were inquiries: it turned out most of the students cited that they found the title of the  book mentioned in the course material attractive which prompted them to enlist.

(We had found in the previous year that the instructor did not care about teaching, insist on taking class at 8 in the morning and would religiously take attendance for 10 minutes, by the end of the class half the class would be snoring. The assignments were to be submitted on A4 paper, we were supposed to write on one side with appropriate margin.

It was a case of a pun / warning which had gone horribly wrong. )

Comment: Stephen Semmes has a real gift for choosing titles for books.  Two other ones : "Where the Buffalo Roam : Infinite Processes and Infinite Complexity" (posted here : http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0302308) and "A graphic apology for symmetry and implicitness" (written w/ Alessandra Carbone).

Comment: "...it had a strange attraction to me..." boom boom!

Answer (score 13):

*How to Gamble If You Must* by Lester E. Dubins & Leonard J. Savage

Answer (score 13):

*The weird and wonderful chemistry of audioactive decay*, by John Conway.

Comment: I've always wanted to read this paper, but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: J.H. Conway, The weird and wonderful chemistry of audioactive decay, in: Open Problems in Communication and Computation, T.M. Cover and B. Gopinath, eds., Springer, 1987, pp. 173–188. If your library doesn't have it, get it through interlibrary loan. 

Answer (score 13):

Speaking of Milnor and such things, have we already done [Edit: Kervaire-Milnor's] "Groups of Homotopy Spheres"?

Comment: That's is a really lovely title.

Comment: +1; In his Abel lecture, Mike Hopkins remarks that Milnor's papers often have this kind of elegant concision: The title almost says it all and by the time you end the first paragraph, you have already learnt a couple of mind-blowing theorems and/or conjectures... 

(BTW, maybe your answer should at least mention the late Kervaire...)

Answer (score 13):

“*Kindergarten Quantum Mechanics*” by Bob Coecke / [arXiv:quant-ph/0510032v1](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0510032v1)

Answer (score 12):

Al Capone and the Death Ray by R. C. Lyness

Comment:  Wow. If you have access to JSTOR: http://www.jstor.org/stable/3606559

Comment: The abstract says, in part, "After illustrating some of the methods by which difficult-looking results can be obtained simply, I shall obtain a simple-looking result with difficulty and ask for an easier way of getting it."

Answer (score 12):

Simmons, F. W., *When Homogeneous Continua Are Hausdorff
Circles (or **Yes, We Hausdorff Bananas**)*, Continua, Decompositions, and Manifolds,
University of Texas Press (1980) pp. 62-73.  I think it's a reference to [this song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes!_We_Have_No_Bananas).

Answer (score 12):

I always like the title "**[Homology flows, cohomology cuts](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/1536414.1536453)**" by Chambers, Erickson and Nayyeri, which makes *analog* (a general technique indeed) to the well-known theorem (for graph theorists) "**Maximum flows, minimum cuts**".

Answer (score 12):

[A Tale of Two Sieves](https://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/PDF/paper109.pdf) by Carl Pomerance

Answer (score 12):

De Weger and Pinter wrote [this paper](http://deweger.xs4all.nl/papers/%5B22%5DPidW-210-PubMatDebr%5B1997%5D.pdf) entitled:

$$210 = 14 \times 15 = 5 \times 6 \times 7 = \binom{21}{2} = \binom{10}{4}$$

Comment: . . . which reminds me that $\displaystyle \binom{3003}1 = \binom{78} 2 = \binom{15} 5 = \binom {14} 6. \qquad$

Answer (score 11):

I like Cliff Taubes's simple titles: "[Gr -> SW](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214425068)", "[SW -> Gr](https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1996-9-03/S0894-0347-96-00211-1/S0894-0347-96-00211-1.pdf)", and "[SW = Gr](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214425348)". (Okay, they each also have a subtitle, but the first part is enough to tell the reader exactly what the paper is about.)

Comment: They tell the reader who is familiar with the subject. I cannot even tell what subject they are about.

Comment: That's true, but I figured any readers looking at papers by that particular author would know what they're about. And everyone in this field certainly knows that author, so there would never be any confusion.

Answer (score 11):

The following is not quite as arresting as the other titles listed, but Stallings has a paper in Inventiones entitled "The topology of finite graphs".  It's a pretty gutsy title, but what's even more impressive is that it is a fairly good description of what the paper contains (namely, a totally new approach to studying questions about subgroups of free groups using finite graphs; this is totally different from the classical approach using covering spaces of graphs)!

Answer (score 11):

Bob Thomason's "[Beware the Phony Multiplication on Quillen's $A^{-1}A$"](https://www.jstor.org/pss/2043425).

Comment: I wanted to post this but I kept forgetting until I was somewhere without Mathscinet 
http://www.jstor.org/stable/2043425?origin=crossref

Answer (score 11):

*Theorems for free!* by [Philip Wadler](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/topics/parametricity.html)

From the abstract: ... This provides a free source of useful theorems, courtesy of Reynolds' abstraction theorem for the polymorphic lambda calculus.

Answer (score 11):

"[What is infinity factorial (and why might we care)?](http://katlas.math.toronto.edu/drorbn/MathBlog/2008-11/one/Gillet@FI-_What_is_infinity_factorial_%28and_why_might_we_care%29Q.pdf)"

The only downside is that it isn't actually typed up, but rather is hand-written and scanned, but the result of $\infty! = \sqrt{2\pi}$ is still rather intriguing.

Answer (score 11):

Here are a few that jump to my mind.

*Young person's guide to canonical singularities* by Miles Reid, 1985.

*Twenty-five years of 3-folds—an old person's view* by Miles Reid, 2000.

*Tendencious survey of 3-folds*, by Miles Reid, 1985 (same book, Bowdoin -- Algebraic Geometry, as the first one).

*On the ubiquity of Gorenstein rings* by Hyman Bass, 1963.  This also seems to be the first paper with the word ubiquity in the title (via a mathscinet search).

Another one that jumps to my mind is the various *Pathologies* papers of Mumford.

Comment: A little late: When I was recent PhD (about 40 years ago), I wrote a paper, *Propinquity of Gorenstein rings* (referring to some classes of Gorenstein subrings being close together), answering a question in *... ubiquity ...*. The paper was accepted by Hy, and appeared in JPAA. Subsequently, I found out that the question had already been answered, by Sally. So I thought about writing a paper entitled *Iniquity of Gorenstein rings*, but couldn't find any suitable results.

Comment: I notice that '[tendencious](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tendencious)' is in the original, not a typo here.  Is this some pun (as compared to the usual spelling '[tendentious](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tendentious#English)')?

Answer (score 11):

You can find in Serre's *Œuvres* (volume IV) an article titled [$\Delta = b^2 - 4ac$](http://pythagoras0.springnote.com/pages/1943100/attachments/871280). ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20121109131026/http://pythagoras0.springnote.com/pages/1943100/attachments/871280))

Answer (score 10):

*Crocheting Adventures with Hyperbolic Planes* by Dr Daina Taimina (A K Peters), see

http://www.thebookseller.com/news/114989-crocheting-adventures-wins-diagram-2009.html ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20100329111102/https://www.thebookseller.com/news/114989-crocheting-adventures-wins-diagram-2009.html))

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookseller/Diagram_Prize_for_Oddest_Title_of_the_Year

http://hyperbolic-crochet.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 10):

*Great Expectations: The Theory of Optimal Stopping,*
Yuan Shih Chow, Herbert Ellis Robbins, David Siegmund
Houghton Mifflin, 1971

Answer (score 10):

Not math, but [Alpher, Bethe, and Gamow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpher%E2%80%93Bethe%E2%80%93Gamow_paper) is hard to beat

Comment: It's not a title, though, is it? Do I foresee a new question about memorable lists of authors? 

Comment: That one is sort of a cruel example, as it was due to Gamow's sense of humor that Bethe was invited; he did not even have anything to do with it.  Alpher was just a student at the time and felt afterwards that his contribution was drowned out by the bigshot names.  (This is all just paraphrased from the Wikipedia article.)

Answer (score 10):

Another one:
[MR1274760](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1274760) (95d:30040)
Carleson, Lennart(S-RIT); Jones, Peter W.(1-YALE); Yoccoz, Jean-Christophe(F-PARIS11)
Julia and John. (English summary)
Bol. Soc. Brasil. Mat. (N.S.) 25 (1994), no. 1, 1–30.

The preprint wad even more memorable title:
In Carleson and Gamelin's book on complex dynamics it was referred to as: When is Julia John?

Answer (score 9):

I hope it is OK to mention "A Disorienting Look at Euler's Theorem on the Axis of a Rotation" even if I am a joint author, particularly if I admit that none of the authors thought up the cute title---it was the editor. (The cute part is the somewhat subtle use of "disorienting", namely we prove Euler's Theorem for orthogonal transformations that are not proper---i.e., don't preserve orientation.) You can download it here:

http://mathdl.maa.org/mathDL/?pa=content&sa=viewDocument&nodeId=3542&pf=1

Answer (score 9):

I have always found the book title "**Prolegomena to a Middlebrow Arithmetic of Curves of Genus 2**" by Cassels and Flynn to be quite memorable.

Answer (score 9):

**A mathematical theory of the guillotine**, by Plero Villaggio, *Archive for Rational Mechanics and Analysis* (1990) Vol. 110, pp 93-101.

Answer (score 8):

[Finding even sets even faster.](https://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=252278)

[The last fraction of a fractional conjecture.](https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.0683)

Answer (score 8):

There's an algebra book called "Rings and Ideals".  I thought of a subtitle: "Marriage during the Revolution".

I remember reading Jacobson's "Basic Algebra I" on the bus on the way to university, and someone noticing it and thinking it was a high-school level text.

Similarly, Serre(?) has a difficult book about number theory, titled simply "Arithmetic".

Comment: +1 for the subtitle. This reminds the course given by C. Foias in Orsay: *Contractions et dilatations*, which could have been given in the Department of Obstetrics.

However, I regret the adjective *difficult*. Jean-Pierre (=?) wrote a concise book, which is so usefull that it is still used by our students after fifty years.

Comment: In the same vein of elementary-looking books, Weil's *Basic Number Theory* is unbeatable.

Comment: And what about Lurie's Higher Algebra?

Answer (score 8):

Andrew Ranicki and the late John Roe were writing

**Surgery for Amateurs**

A spectacularly funny title, I think.

The incomplete, but very nice, notes can be found online. Thanks again to Nigel Higson for his lovely talk remembering John Roe in the UK Virtual Operator Algebras Seminar.

Comment: Does "Virtual" modify "Operator", or "Algebra", or "Seminar"?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: the seminar is virtual, not the operator algebras. :)

Answer (score 8):

However the question is about papers but it is worth mentioning the title  of Ketonen's PhD thesis: "[Everything You Wanted to Know About Ultrafilters But Were Afraid to Ask](https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=9186)" !

Answer (score 8):

[Kevin Buchin, Maike Buchin, Christian Knauer, Günter Rote, Carola Wenk, *How Difficult is it to Walk the Dog?*, In: Abstracts of the 23rd European Workshop on Computational Geometry, Graz, March 2007, pp. 170-173](https://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/rote/Papers/abstract/How+difficult+is+it+to+walk+the+dog.html).

"Walking the dog" refers to finding parametrizations $a : [0,1]\to C$ and $b : [0,1]\to D$ of two curves $C$ and $D$ such that $\max_{t\in[0,1]} \|a(t) - b(t)\|$ is as small as possible -- or at least smaller than a given cutoff value. The metaphor is a person walking along curve $C$ while keeping a dog on a leash walking along curve $D$. The famous "simultaneous mountain climbers" puzzle has a cameo.

Answer (score 7):

[Ancestors, Cardinals, and Representatives](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2323341) by T. D. Parsons.

Comment: Could the (apparently anonymous at this time) person who voted this one down explain their rationale?  This posting is similar in content to many of those above that were voted up.

Answer (score 7):

I just saw the very curious title:

*An Operator-Like Description of Love Affairs*

by: Fabio Bagarello and Francesco Oliveri
SIAM J. Appl. Math. Volume 70, Issue 8, pp. 3235-3251 (2010)

And with the report of this title, I also admit that this title belongs to the category of memorable titles, without first needing to read the paper. The abstract of the paper is also quite curious!

Answer (score 7):

[Smale, Stephen. The story of the higher-dimensional Poincaré conjecture (what actually happened on the beaches of Rio de Janeiro). A joint AMS-MAA invited address presented in Phoenix, Arizona, January 1989. AMS-MAA Joint Lecture Series. American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 1989. 1 videocassette (NTSC; 1/2 inch; VHS) (60 min.); sd., col. [MR1057609](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR1057609) (91g:01035)]

It's a video, but it's Smale, so...

Answer (score 7):

[On manifolds homeomorphic to the 7-sphere](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/exotic.pdf)

In which Milnor proves there is more than one.

Answer (score 7):

On the more applied side of things, I'm quite fond of the following (sub)title:

[Estimating the number of unseen species: A bird in the hand is worth $\log n$ in the bush](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.07428)

Answer (score 6):

[Marginalia to a theorem of Silver](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0079419) (see also this [link](https://books.google.com/books?id=9UHU_bq-wc8C&pg=PA13)) by Keith I. Devlin and R. B. Jensen, 1975. A humble title and yet, undoubtedly, one of the most important papers of all time in set theory.

Answer (score 6):

I'll echo other comments that the question is wrong-headed, but I think it still serves a purpose.

Comment l'hypothese de Riemann ne fut pas prouvee (How the Riemann hypothesis was not proved), by P Cartier, Seminar on Number Theory, Paris 1980-81, Progr. Math., 22, Boston, MA: Birkhauser Boston, pp. 35-48, [MR693308](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=693308)

Answer (score 6):

Knobel's wonderful paper on the constant rediscovery of iterated exponentials.

> R. Knobel. "Exponentials Reiterated." American Mathematical Monthly 88, (1981), p. 235-252.

Answer (score 6):

"A survey of finite differences of opinion on numerical muddling of the incomprehensible defective confusion equation" by B.P. Leonard

Answer (score 6):

Larry Bates, Monodromy in the champagne bottle.

Answer (score 6):

Larry Bates, "You can't get there from here", Differential Geometry and its Applications 8.3 (1998): 273-274

Comment: There = a hotel?

Answer (score 6):

The book of Serge Lang: $\mathrm{SL}_2(\Bbb R)$.

*Lang, Serge*, $\mathrm{SL}_2(\Bbb R)$, Reading, Mass. etc.: Addison-Wesley Publishing Company. XVI, 428 p. $19.50 (1975). [ZBL0311.22001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0311.22001).

Comment: Serge Lang: Too Real.

Answer (score 6):

[A Cohomological Viewpoint on Elementary School Arithmetic](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3072368)

Answer (score 5):

Most colorful:

[MR1371379](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1371379) (97g:60105)
Chung, Kai Lai:
Green, Brown, and probability. World Scientific Publishing Co., Inc., River Edge, NJ, 1995. xiv+106 pp. ISBN: 981-02-2453-2; 981-02-2533-4

The book discusses connection between potential theory (in particular Green's function for Laplace equation) and probability (in particular Brownian motions).

Answer (score 5):

"K-theory doesn't exist" by Ethan Akin: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404978900324

Answer (score 5):

Gaetano Fichera's "Avere una memoria tenace crea gravi problemi" [Having a persistent memory creates serious problems], (Italian), Archive for Rational Mechanics and Analysis 70, 101-112 (1979), [MR1553577](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR1553577), [Zbl 0425.73002](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0425.73002).

The title is a pun to introduce the Author's analysis of time dependent kernels in continuum mechanics: he shows that, while Volterra type kernels (i.e. kernels which are zero before a fixed time $t$ in the past) can be used in the integrodifferential equations of elasticity without affecting existence and uniqueness results involved, the use of general kernels make these results strongly dependent of the topology of the function space on which the problem is posed. The pun is also explained with an analogy at the end of the paper.

Answer (score 5):

My personal favorite is Elisabetta A. Matsumoto's:

*"The Taming of the Screw: or How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love Elliptic Functions"*

which can be found [here](https://repository.upenn.edu/edissertations/306/). It is a very good read, and the title extremely seamlessly references both Shakespeare and Dr.Strangelove; two of my favorites.

Comment: And a nod to [Henry James](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Turn_of_the_Screw) as well!

Answer (score 4):

My Ph.D. thesis is titled *Why Logical Probabilists Need Real Numbers*.  (But I haven't published any paper with that title.)

Comment: And... why do they?

Comment: Start by thinking of probabilities as belonging to some partially ordered set lacking such amenities as the operations of addition and multiplication.  Then under certain assumptions that are reasonable in some epistemic situations, one can show that they might as well be real numbers with the usual order and the usual operations.

Comment: Doesn't a PhD thesis count as a paper?


Comment: @Zsbán: Maybe it's a matter of convention.  I haven't submitted anything to a journal with this title, but maybe I should have.  My thesis contained some big sections explaining some background material to my advisor.  I did write a paper on the same general topic with the unexciting title "Scaled Boolean Algebras".

Answer (score 4):

[**Mathematical Fallacies, Flaws and Flimflam**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0883855291) was definitely by far the most memorable title I have ever read. Also **A Taste of Topology** seemed tasty.

But I would also like to stress, that to me, the books that have the most 'classical' and 'general' titles, seem the most appealing. Eg.

- [**Graph Theory**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849966907),
- [**Algebraic Topology**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521795400),
- [**Algebraic Geometry**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1441928073),
- [**Abstract Algebra**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1441924507),

etc.

Answer (score 4):

One title I delight in having on my bookshelf is "Introduction to Group Characters" by Walter Ledermann - if you know it's a maths book the title makes complete sense. But a non-mathematician imagines a completely different kind of content.

Comment: There's a Wikipdia article titled ''group action''.  What must the lay reader expect it to be about?

Comment: Reminds my of books with titles like "Theory of normal families". I've been told that one of these could be found in the "social sciences" section the university library in Bremen... 

Comment: When I was in charge of acquiring books for our math-library, books on "Group therapy" or similar stuff showed sometimes up in a  list of math-books.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a big fan of "[Excluding a Forest](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6WHT-4JMV5P1-6&_user=10&_coverDate=08/31/1983&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=gateway&_origin=gateway&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_searchStrId=1744513514&_rerunOrigin=google&_acct=C000050221&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=10&md5=8f5bda5bab769d3bcb246b0c9860e60f&searchtype=a)": technically precise, to the point, but just mysterious enough to grab the attention. I've said before that it ought to be the name of a band. ("Taming a vortex" is also good.)

Comment: The link in the post no longer works. A quick [google search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=%22Excluding%20a%20Forest%22) suggests that it might be probably one of the papers *Graph minors. I. Excluding a forest* or *Quickly excluding a forest*.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Based on the fact that the broken URL has the string `coverDate=9/31/1983`, I'm fairly sure that it is meant to point to the paper "Graph minors. I. Excluding a forest". This article is available at [doi:10.1016/0095-8956(83)90079-5](https://doi.org/10.1016/0095-8956(83)90079-5) ([Zbl 0521.05062](https://zbmath.org/0521.05062)).

Answer (score 4):

Mathematical physics, for the allusion: "**The Unbearable Beingness of Light, Dressing and Undressing Photons in Black Hole Spacetimes**" by Timothy J. Hollowood, Graham M. Shore

Comment: Hint: Czech writer

Comment: Must read the book or see the movie (PG recommended for the young, preferably nontoxic, sexually secure parents) to understand the full set of puns in the title.

Comment: Ah, the Czech author of "The Unbearable . . ."  just passed. Several fine eulogies were given on EU public broadcasting channels.

Answer (score 3):

I really like humor in scientific texts, specially in titles. One of my favorite authors is Donald E. Knuth. A title like *The sandwich theorem* makes me curious about its content. *The Art of Computer Programming* is also a nice title.

Answer (score 3):

I like the second part of:

Breuil, Christophe; Conrad, Brian; Diamond, Fred; Taylor, Richard "On the modularity of elliptic curves over $\mathbf{Q}$: *wild 3-adic exercises*."

[MR1839918](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1839918) (2002d:11058)

They prove the remaining cases of the Shimura-Taniyama conjecture: "every elliptic curve is modular".

Answer (score 3):

["A short tale of hybrid mice"](http://grigorsargis.weebly.com/uploads/2/8/9/7/2897376/bsl.pdf), by Grigor Sargsyan.

Comment: The link gives a pdf with the title "Descriptive inner model theory". (At least now.)

Answer (score 3):

[The Chekanov torus in $S^2\times S^2$ is not real](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.09972). Quite a philosophical title and I could never forget about it...

Comment: I had a working title on a paper of "On a virtual object which may not exist". Sadly I didn't have the gumption to follow through.

Answer (score 3):

[Using the Logistic Map to Generate Scratching Sounds](https://www.mathematica-journal.com/2013/05/27/using-the-logistic-map-to-generate-scratching-sounds/)

The first sentence in the abstract:

> This article presents a mathematical model for generating annoying
> scratching sounds.

Answer (score 3):

[Honey, I Shrunk the Sample Covariance Matrix](https://jpm.pm-research.com/content/30/4/110)

Answer (score 2):

[Quantum lower bounds by quantum arguments](https://doi.acm.org/10.1145/335305.335394).

Answer (score 2):

Some nice titles from B.A. Kupersmidt:

- [KP or mKP](http://www.mathjournals.org/bookstore?fn=20&arg1=survseries&ikey=SURV-78) (a book)
- [Dark equations](http://staff.www.ltu.se/~norbert/home_journal/electronic/83art3.pdf) (an article)

Answer (score 2):

Smullyan: [what is the name of this book?](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/493576.What_Is_the_Name_of_This_Book_)

Mazzola: [The Topos of Music](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783764357313)

Answer (score 2):

« Autopsie d'un meurtre » dans l'homologie d'une algèbre de chaînes ("Anatomy of a murder" in the homology of a chain algebra)
by J.-M. Lemaire,
http://www.numdam.org/item/ASENS_1978_4_11_1_93_0/

(For those who do not care about old movies as much as I do, the title of course alludes to the iconic film of Otto Preminger https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatomy_of_a_Murder)

Answer (score 2):

["49598666989151226098104244512918"](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jnt.2013.11.001) by Michael Filaseta and Samuel Gross

Comment: Is this really *memorable*?

Comment: I admit I went with "A title can be attractive even without having memorable material" with this one - certainly got me attracted to spend searching Cohn irreducibility criterion wiki page history to find out who entered such non-sense :o

Comment: @Sil I think Emil Jeřábek was intending a pun on the difficulty to memorize that hell of a number.

Answer (score 1):

Mickley, Smith and Korchak's Fluid flow in packed beds.

(No-one in fluid mechanics seems to be willing to see the innuendo. They
all want to explain the effect on the Reynolds number. And they hate it
if you snigger when they mention turbulence.)

Answer (score 1):

[Old and new on SL(2)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01171699) by Hilgert and Hofmann. I heard that the authors wrote a sequel with the title *More is true on SL(2)*, but that the editors insisted on a different title.

Comment: The sequel should have been "SL(2) II, Electric Boogalo."

Answer (score -2):

Would a book titled *Calculus Made Honest* get me burned at the stake for heresy?

Or would it merely confuse mathematicians who don't understand what is in need of being made honest in that topic?

**Later edit:** This question illustrates nicely the emotional nature of the anonymous voting system.  Robin Chapman commented: "So, it isn't an actual title, and so this reply is not an answer to the original question."

That proves that he never read the original question and didn't know what it said.  Probably he drew an inference about its content from the many answers.  Then people rushed in with "down" votes.  I invite anyone who has doubts about this to read the original question by Suvrit, and I invite Robin Chapman to read it for the first time.

[Original answer by **Michael Hardy**.]

Comment: It might find a place on my shelves next to Mathematics Made Difficult, by Carl Linderholm, http://www.amazon.com/Mathematics-made-difficult-Carl-Linderholm/dp/0529045524

Comment: That book was dedicated (in a manner that those familiar with modal logic might enjoy) "To Clement Durrell, without whom this book would not have been necessary."

But actually I had in mind a work of non-fiction.

Comment: Is *Calculus Made Honest* an actual title?

Comment: @Robin: It is working title of a book that might exist if I compile and extend various things I've written.  The conventional assembly-line-style calculus course that innumerable students are coerced to take was designed as follows: start with a course appropriate for students who are interested in math and want to learn a lot about it, and then water it down a lot.  That is inappropriate as a course for certain students who differ from both those who major in math and those who are there because they are coerced.  This would be suitable for a different kind of audience.

Comment: @Robin: The aforementioned coercion does result in dishonesty, and not only in the form of students cheating on exams.  The course is forced to become something that students who resent being coerced will survive.  A bunch of algorithms are presented; a little bit is said about what they mean but there is very little of that that students are expected to understand.  And _in effect_ they're told "That is what mathematics is."  I've recently begun to appreciate that some mathematicians are protected from finding out about such things.

Comment: @Robin: I had thought my way of phrasing my posting made clear what I said in the first sentence of my reply to your question.

Comment: Could the anonymous persons who voted this down step forward and say something in this comment space?  I am mystified by this reaction, so an explanation could be useful.  I think the denizens of this forum should be competent to express themselves verbally; I think if I had something critical to say about a posting that I thought was worth voting down, I would say something.  But no one has in this case.

Comment: So, it isn't an actual title, and so this reply is not an
answer to the original question.

Comment: Nonetheless it bears upon the topic, in that I would propose that this would be more memorable than other titles.  Other such proposed titles attempting to improve on whatever's out there would also bear on the topic.

Comment: Just to be completely clear: Robin Chapman is confused.  He says I wasn't answering the original question, simply because my answer didn't give a title of a published paper.  But the original question was not ONLY a request for such titles.  Apparently Robin Chapman didn't finish reading the original question, and then he drew this conclusion that he would see to be incorrect if he had read it.

Comment: Robin Chapman is asserting elsewhere that I posted this answer only as a pretext for a polemic.  At this point I can only surmise that he views my comments above as a polemic, and thinks that I posted for the purpose of posting those.  But I posted them only in reply to Robin Chapman's question that I'd have thought he'd already know the answer to, because of the way I phrased my posting.

Answer (score -2):

The Chemical Basis of Morphogenesis. Alan Turing.

A math paper use chemical principles explaining biological phenomenon.